exe файл не находит tkdnd
Сделал простой тестовый скрипт с использованием Drag And Drop
import tkinter as tk
from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, DND_FILES

def on_drop(event):
    # Когда файл перетаскивается в Entry, его путь отображается в поле
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)  # Очистить текущий текст
    entry.insert(0, event.data)  # Вставить путь к файлу

# Создаем главное окно с расширением для drag-and-drop
root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
root.title("Drag and Drop Example")

# Создаем Entry виджет
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
entry.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

# Разрешаем перетаскивание файлов на Entry
entry.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
entry.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', on_drop)

root.mainloop()

После компиляции pyinstaller и последующем запуске exe получаю сообщение:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinterdnd2\TkinterDnD.py", line 55, in _require
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tkdnd

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 57, in <module>
  File "tkinterdnd2\TkinterDnD.py", line 287, in __init__
  File "tkinterdnd2\TkinterDnD.py", line 57, in _require
RuntimeError: Unable to load tkdnd library.

Библиотека установлена. В IDE скрипт работает правильно. Проблема возникает при запуске exe. Как исправить?

Надо перестать из питона экзешники делать. Ну а вообще наверняка нужно ее в импорты при сборке прописать

Если "Надо перестать из питона экзешники делать" то как же их тогда запускать?? На клиентских машинах сам Python устанавливать? Что касается импорта. То прописывал через --add-data все равно не работает.

Не заниматься ерундой. Экзешники на питоне никому не нужны. А по вашему вопросу первая ссылка в гугле - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69348567/pyinstaller-tkdnd-tkinterdnd2-unable-to-load-tkdnd-library-when-launching-fr

Научите все таки других как вы обходитесь без exe. При распространения своих программ вы включаете в инсталлятор дистрибутив Python? После установки пользователь скачивает и импортирует всевозможные модули, фреймворки, настраивает зависимости, потом все это периодически обновляет и т.д.? Не, на а чо? :-) Действительно, очень оригинальное и главное, простое решение! И вы говорите, так все поступают? "Экзешники на питоне никому не нужны"? :-))

Нет, конечному пользователю не доставляются exe приложения. Обычно это веб-приложения. Хотите ехе? Вперед на СИ. Ну и так, для справки, pyinstaller упаковывает питон и потом распаковывает его со всеми зависимостями :)

Никаких проблем с pyinstaller, конечно же, нет. Выясняется причина "проблемы", как минимум, по трём направлениям. 1) Программа должна работать автономно, то есть путём запуска главного .py в операционной системе. Если отработает как надо, значит и автономная сборка соберётся. 2) Избавьтесь от from и никогда не используйте. Да-да. 3) Непонятно, как именно Вы собираете пакет в pyinstaller. Да-да. Это Вам только кажется, возможно, что Вы делаете это эффективно и правильно. Я пользуюсь сборками pyinstaller давно. Чего-чего, а проблем с отсутствующим модулем не видел ни разу у себя.

"1) Программа должна работать автономно, то есть путём запуска главного .py в операционной системе."  В IDE программа работает идеально. никаких проблем.


Избавьтесь от from и никогда не используйте." Чем можно заменить строку: from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, DND_FILES что бы не было from?
Непонятно, как именно Вы собираете пакет в pyinstaller.    Собирал всевозможными способами. Но для простоты даже самый элементарный pyinstaller myfile.py дает ошибку.     Пробовал так же pyinstaller.exe --collect-all TkinterDnD2 --windowed   и с подключением хука. Все равно идет ошибка.

